# Is it possible to overlay pixel graphics with vector graphics

Tags: graphics

I would like to add annotations to a pixel graphics. The text should be in vector font and whatever graphics I add (e.g., lines) should be in vector format, too. Let's take a simple example:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
im = Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 100]}, ImageSize -> 200];
rec = Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {50, 5}]}, ImageSize -> 50];
text = Graphics[{Black, Text["some text"]}, ImageSize -> 100];
ov = ImageCompose[ImageCompose[im, rec, {150, 55}], text, {150, 65}];
Export["test.pdf", ov]
```

Let's say that `im` is a pixel graphics and I can't do anything about that (in reality for instance an imported png file), but the overlaid text and rectangle are mathematica objects and I want them to be rendered as vector objects. Is that possible with mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use Show to combine appropriate graphics objects, then Export to a vector-capable format like PDF, and you'll see that the text and graphics are retained in vector format:

```
Show[
 ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Airplane2"}],
 Graphics[{
   Red, Rectangle[{100, 100}, {210, 140}],
   Inset[
     Style["some text", 32, White, Background -> Blue],
     Scaled[{0.3, 0.75}]
   ]
 }]
]

Export["test.pdf", %]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]